# try plotting an iteration but plt.plot is empty

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

```
a = frame_query("select ....",db)
```

With my code, the var 'c' is a numpy.ndarray which I would like to plot. However when I execute the following code, i get an empty plot!

```
for i in a.values:
    c = (i[:1]-a.values[-1:])/a.values[-1:]*100
    plt.plot(c)
plt.show()

print c
```

gives:

```
[[ 28.57142857]]
[[ 27.27272727]]
[[ 27.92207792]]
[[ 28.57142857]]
[[ 22.07792208]]
[[ 22.07792208]]
[[ 22.07792208]]
```

Where exactly am I going wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more context? What exactly is `a`? At least for me it's not obvious that `c` is in fact a vector.

Comment: Try printing `c` and seeing what comes out.

Comment: Are you sure that is *exactly* what the output shows for `print c`? Can you do `print type(c)` as well?  If `c` is an `ndarray` - I'd expect `print c` to give something like `array([[ 28.57142857],
       [ 27.27272727],
       [ 27.92207792],
       [ 28.57142857],
       [ 22.07792208],
       [ 22.07792208],
       [ 22.07792208]])`.  However, if it is an `ndarray` like that, it should plot fine using `plt.plot(c)` (it does on my machine)

Comment: there are 30 items, the first five are [[-0.64935065]]
[[-2.5974026]]
[[-1.2987013]]
[[-1.2987013]]
[[ 1.2987013]]
[[ 0.]]
[[ 0.]]   Type(c) is literally 30 instances of <type 'numpy.ndarray'>. You are correct, its just that the problem I believe is that it is plotting only ONE point, and therefore gives 30 individual plots for each iteration in the list. Perhaps I can catch or concatenate all then plot?

Comment: OK - I've given an answer.  As an aside - with `print c` in the position shown in the code - I think it would only print the last instance of `c`, not a list as you show.  That's a bit confusing.  I'll try to edit your question so that it's specific for any readers that find the question in future.  Good luck with your programming - if the solution works let me know and [accept :)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to adapt your code is probably to start an empty list before the loop, append the values from `c` onto it within the loop and then plot it after the loop.  For example:

```
c_series = []

for i in a.values:
    c = (i[:1]-a.values[-1:])/a.values[-1:]*100
    c_series.append(c[0])

plt.plot(c)
plt.show()
```

***Note*** using `c[0]` is safe here, because the logic of the line above guarantees that the `ndarray` will only have one member.

***However***, that's a bit of an odd way to deal with your data structure.  As it seems that `a.values` is an `ndarray`, you could also simply do this by using the facilities that numpy provides to perform arithmetical operations on arrays (I can't test it as I don't have a verbatim copy of your `a.values`):

```
const = a.values[-1:]
c_series = (a.values - const) / const*100
plt.plot(c_series)
plt.show()
```

In general - when using numpy arrays, it's often better to keep them as arrays (called vectorising the code), rather than dealing with them element by element in a loop.